# What is this drawing style called?

Tags: drawing, style-identification, art

I was drawing in class and somehow created this and I want to make more of these tho I don't know how this is called?

Can someone please help???
[image]

Comment: ermm.. pen and ink possibly. Not everything has a name.

Comment: If anyone knows, can this question be asked here too? https://crafts.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I were to sell this at some sort of marketplace. Not that I have experience in that, but from the perspective of someone who has bought a few illustrations. Well first of all it would probably have to be vectorized and maybe it could also have a cleaned up raster version in png format with the background cut out. Any price would be too much just for a raw photo or a scan. And then I might call it something like: `Wolf line drawing` or `Wolf doodle`. Calling it a `doodle` might not work if the finalized form of it is too clean/doesn't look hand drawn.

Comment: Doodle usually means something that is kinda rough, which I think applies, assuming you don't make the lines any cleaner (like your avatar). But still, clean or not `line drawing` works in either case. If you were thinking you'd have a bundle of many animal drawings, then perhaps `Animal line drawings` or `Animal doodles`. It pays the be as specific as possible though so maybe adding `Forest` in the front would make sense, as long as you stick to forest animals.

Comment: @Vikas, I would say no. Even in here, it's a little too subjective and more to do with marketing than graphic design.

Comment: @Joonas not on crafts because it would be off topic there or it would be subjective? I saw there are people asking about drawings and paintings. So I felt it would fit there as it's more about art than graphic design.

Comment: To continue the thought from my first two comments, adding the word `stylized` in there might not be a bad idea. And replacing the word `drawing` with `illustration` might work. A lot of this would depend on what's already there in a marketplace. Like you might want to separate yourself a little, but not too much to the point where yours is the only result but nobody would ever think to look for it.

Comment: @Vikas I'd say both. It's very subjective. We could sit here or there all day going back and forth with what we think is the correct naming, but I think in either site the final nail in the coffin is that it's really a marketing question. OP doesn't need to know what the style of drawing is called to make more. So I'm thinking he has to be thinking about selling them or putting them somewhere for free, so that's why I would say it's a "marketing" question. If it was about finding similar drawings, it might fit in either place at least more than right now. I don't feel very strongly either way.

Comment: @Joonas fair enough. Anyway I wonder why they don't have site description. I tried to search what crafts site is all about. But it did have tags like drawing and painting. If I have a question about art, can I ask there?

Answer (score 3):

Cute drawing. I don't think you will be able to find a *name of a style* you can search for though.

The *medium* is pen or ink on paper, but that's not a *style*. One could move a pen around on paper in an infinite number of ways. How could we give them *all* names?

I know that feeling of doing several drawings and then suddenly make *one* that I feel has something *special* about it. But it can be hard to pinpoint exactly what it is. Is it the shape of the lines? The lines themselves? The shadowing? The colors? The motif?

I think what you are searching for is in fact **your own personal style**.

Every artist struggles to make something that is *unique* and *personal*. The challenge is to look at what others do and learn from that, but at the same time try to forget it again and zoom in on your own stuff and just draw from intuition.

Comment: Can't we call it doodle?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's a small sample and black&white photo. I try to imagine it in color and shown as a part of some bigger image where it can belong to. The result:

[image]

I would call it "phone notebook scribble". But in this case the maker of the top right corner shape very likely can draw and invent something interesting to draw, no matter the lines look coarse.

Comment: You are not doing it justice. Why not [print it in two Pantone colors, frame it and sell it as art](https://i.imgur.com/XAVxj7o.jpeg)?

Comment: Of course it can be a piece of art. As I said, the maker can draw and invent something interesting to draw. My own creations are much closer to the rest of the notebook paper content as you have probably seen during the recent years.

Comment: @Wolff will people buy it? Anything we draw which is unique like this can be sold?

Comment: @Vikas, there's always a chance... I mean: [JPG File Sells for $69 Million, as ‘NFT Mania’ Gathers Pace](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/11/arts/design/nft-auction-christies-beeple.html)

Comment: @Joonas that image has years of efforts. Isn't it? Even if it weren't sold for $69 million, it still deserved to be sold. What I was asking that could this OP's individual image or any similar style art be sold easily or you first have to establish yourself and make a good platform to sell?

Comment: @Vikas, realistically speaking though, doodles get sold all the time in graphic market places https://creativemarket.com/search?q=Animal+doodles

Comment: @Joonas but again, each item there has a lot of details and each is basically a collection, hence lot of time spent :D Which makes sense.

Comment: @Vikas, is it out of your reach to draw 5 animals? I don't really get where you're going with this. If something like 5-10 doodles sell for $5-10 then I'm sure you could sell one with just $1. You're not going to make money by selling dirt. Well you might, but you probably won't. It's not a surprise to anyone that you need some effort to earn money (usually).

Comment: @Joonas yeah that's what I meant. I find it hard to sell my own pencil drawings where I spend so much time. So I wonder would it be so easy to just draw something in few minutes and sell it. That's it.